# PyMongo Bulk Upsert Performance for 100k records

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I'm using PyMongo to bulk upsert ~100k documents every day. Most of the documents will be updated, and ~100 will be created. I'm using the below code in to perform a bulk write operation, but it currently takes ~36 seconds for 200 documents, which would translate to ~5 hours for 100k documents, and I'm wondering how I can optimise it?

```
from pymongo import MongoClient, UpdateOne

# Connect to Mongo
client = MongoClient(mongo_key)
db = client.db_name

def send_mongo(data, my_list):

    operations = []
    
    # Loop through new data to prepare it for mongo
    for p, li in zip(data, my_list):

        # core data
        custom_id = li.get_text()
        core_data = p['info']          
        rela_data = p['rels']

        operations.append(
            UpdateOne(
                {
                    "cust_id": custom_id
                },
                { 
                    "$set": { 
                        "cust_id": custom_id,
                        "core": core_data,
                        "releases": rels_data,
                    }
                },
                upsert=True
            )
        )

        # Send once every 1000 in batch
        if ( len(operations) == 1000 ):
            db.Collection.bulk_write(operations,ordered=False)
            operations = []
```

Comment: Your second if causes every operation to be written in its own command.

Comment: As per previous comment; looks like the second if should be outside the for loop.

Comment: Thanks @D.SM - updated it to remove that but performance is still extremely slow.

Comment: Did you create in index on the `cust_id` field?

Comment: @Joe thanks, yes I did. This speeds things up but it is still not as fast as I'd expect. ~30-40 mins for 100k documents.

Comment: Two things to try: get the timing of each bulk_write to see if there is much variation, and try running with `explain` to see how the operations are handled.